# Creating a db in chicken scheme

Tags: lisp, scheme, chicken-scheme

I would like to ask if it is possible to create a db in chicken scheme; something analogous to this:

http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/practical-a-simple-database.html

If it is then what predicates do i have to read/search for? Should i use an egg?
In the chicken wiki i have made search but have not found what i search. Is it just impossible to implement something like the above in scheme or it's done in a comletely different way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible, but you'll need to use another datatype.

Unlike Common Lisp (which that book focuses on), Schemes don't have `plist`s since they lack the `:keyword` package. You'll need to decide how to store your data, and that decision will affect how you have to construct your `make-` and `select` equivalents. For example, if you decide that `alist`s are a good enough substitute, then getting a property from one of your records is going to look like

```
(cdr (assoc foo record))
```

rather than

```
(getf :foo record)
```

Comment: But the database libraries in the index are supposed to be used for sql databases...Or it does not mind? I mean is it proper to use this kind of databases?

Comment: @yaku  Additionally there is an egg called `kvlists` that adds the same functionality provided by Common Lisp